# WSO2 API Manager failed due to insufficient disk space and not working after restart

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

The WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 instance was running properly till the ec2 instance ran out of disk space. Once the disk was cleared and API Manager restarted, it is throwing errors continuously. It creates access tokens but cannot persist/validate.

Error details:

```
    TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 09:43:14,684]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO} -  Thread pool size for session persistent consumer : 100 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-10-20 09:43:15,495] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenPersistenceTask} -  Error occurred while persisting access token :b4f68332-4359-3718-a553-3d908618b1c6 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenPersistenceTask}
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error when storing the access token for consumer key : _hWq2BEkf1kB2RFSzugOzF04VRsa
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.storeAccessToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:291)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.persistAccessToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:343)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenPersistenceTask.run(TokenPersistenceTask.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: rowCount expected 663 got 665 IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.PRIMARY_KEY_F"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN (ACCESS_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN, CONSUMER_KEY_ID, AUTHZ_USER, TENANT_ID, USER_DOMAIN, TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, VALIDITY_PERIOD, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, TOKEN_SCOPE_HASH, TOKEN_STATE, USER_TYPE, TOKEN_ID, GRANT_TYPE, SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER) SELECT ?,?,ID,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? FROM IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS WHERE CONSUMER_KEY=? [50000-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:156)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:279)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:134)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:148)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:82)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:70)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:199)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:179)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.storeAccessToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:269)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowCount expected 663 got 665 IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN.PRIMARY_KEY_F
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:226)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.checkRowCount(RegularTable.java:144)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:117)
    ... 11 more
TID: [-1] [] [2017-10-20 09:43:16,236]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} -  Starting polling event receivers {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your H2 database is corrupted. You can recover this by clearing H2 database, but you will lose your data.

```
rm -r <APIM_HOME>/repository/database/*
```

Then start server with `-Dsetup`

```
./wso2server.sh -Dsetup
```

This will create H2 database again.

WSO2's recommendation is to not to use H2 in production due to this exact reason (i.e.corruptible nature of H2 databases).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Before trying that I was hoping for some solution to recover the data.

Comment: You can give a try connecting to the database and backup data.
http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html#h2_console